# What is this expression in big O notation?

Tags: asymptotics

$$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} + \ldots + 2$$

pretty basic question, but I'm afraid I don't know if it's $O(2^n)$ or $2^{O(n)}$

Comment: $O(2^{n})$ is a much stronger statement (smaller upperbound) than $2^{O(n)}$  because the first means $\leq C\cdot 2^{n}$ whereas the latter means $\leq 2^{Cn}$.  $2^{Cn}>C2^{n}$ provided that $C$ isn't very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an exponential run time, therefore it is the first one.

This is another place to look if you are confused:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation